# Why can't I vote two times to reopen a question?

Tags: support, questions, reopen, vote-to-close

[This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/623492/) question received hot attention initially. Then it was closed. I and others didn't agree and voted to reopen. And so it was. Then, again, the question was closed. I wanted to reopen it, but couldn't. I think the ones who closed it could close it again. Luckily the question was reopened, and so it is now. But why can't I vote to reopen again? Is this a privilege for moderators only?

Comment: It is closed as of now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the help center](/help/privileges/close-questions):

> Questions can go through multiple close and reopen cycles, but each individual user may cast at most one close and one reopen vote per question.

A restriction like this makes it harder for a small group of persistent voters to override the community's intent on a controversial question, by persistently re-opening a bad question or persistently re-closing a good one.  Note that on *un*-controversial questions,

> Close votes age away harmlessly if the threshold is not reached after a number of days. If the question has at least 100 views, close votes will age away after 4 days; otherwise close votes will age away after 14 days. Each new close vote resets the timer, so all close votes must be at least 4 or 14 days old respectively before aging occurs.

The ability to re-cast an aged-away close vote [may be newer than that part of the documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/280545).